# Run phpunit with custom php path

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, php-7

I'm working on Redhat server, I'm going to add unit test (PHPUnit) to an existing application, PHP is installed on custom path  `/logi/php7211` (I shouldn't change any configuration), when I run the command `php -v`  I get -`bash: php : commande introuvable` (This is not a probleme for me).

When I run the command `/logi/php7211/bin/php -v` I get `PHP 7.2.11 (cli)`

I've installed php using

```
➜ wget -O phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-5.phar

➜ chmod +x phpunit
```

When I run the command  `./phpunit --version` I get the error `/usr/bin/env: php: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type`

How can I add the path of php (/logi/php7211/bin/php) to phpunit  ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I've to run `/logi/php7211/bin/php ./phpunit --version`

Comment: Please mark your question as the answer if it solved it. This should be possible by now and will help future visitors.